# how to give custom JNDI name to an EJB 3.0 bean in WebSphere

Tags: java, java-ee-5

Can any one let me know how to give custom JNDI name to an EJB 3.0 stateless (local) session bean component in WebSphere 7? I know server is giving default name to some thing like `ejblocal:<fully qualified interface name>`. But I dont want to use this name in my client lookup.

I also would like to know whether the same approach will work for WebSphere 8.0 as well?

Answer (score -2):

```
interface @Remote 
public interface HellowWorldBeanRemote {} 
bean class import javax.ejb.Stateless; 
@Stateless(mappedName="HelloWorld") //Giving custom Jndi name to ejb 
public class HellowWorldBean implements HellowWorldBeanRemote {}
```